# bitcoin-cli not found on OSX

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, mac, installation

I have a Qt testnet3 node synched and running on my mac.  In the terminal, when simply trying:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getinfo
```

or

```
$ ./bitcoin-cli getinfo
```

I get:

```
-bash: bitcoin-cli: command not found
```

Anyone know why the command could or would not be found?  (server=1 in bitcoin.conf as well)

Comment: Are you sure `bitcoind`  is actually running?

Comment: I'm running Qt, so bitcoind would not be running.  Pretty sure I have the necessary configurations in my .conf to run RPC commands.

Comment: I know on my other computer I wasn't able to execute commands until the blockchain was caught up for mainnet, or that is what seemed to happen, but I was hoping I could just run a testnet on this computer, and just have the testnet blockchain... maybe not, or maybe having a blockchain doesn't matter.

Comment: So, here I'm confused about two things. Bitcoin-Qt was renamed Bitcoin Core at least since Bitcoin 0.9.1, we are currently at version 0.12.0. So, hopefully, you are running Bitcoin Core? ;) The other is, I'm not sure that Bitcoin Core provides the JSON-RPC interface, I'm sure that `bitcoind` (the daemon) does, though. So, you might want to try running `bitcoind -daemon` instead. I have no clue whether any of this is the same for Mac, though.

Comment: I am running core, and you may have missed previous comment, but JSON-RPC does work with Core (Qt) on my other computer.  Both are running v0.12, although on this one, I may not have installed bitcoind, as I don't believe it is necessary if I am running qt, although I may be wrong and that may be the problem.

Comment: Okay, then I don't know. Carry on!

Comment: I assume you checked whether your current directory actually contains the bitcoin-cli file and that it's executable?

Comment: I checked just now and I don't see one, however I don't see one on my other computer either, and the commands work just fine on that one.  What and where is this bitcoin-cli file you speak of?  I assumed such a file or functionality would be in place with installation.

Comment: Bah, I did a make install to install Bitcoind, and all is good!

Comment: Do you use Bitcoin Core GUI version?

Answer (score 9):

There is a bitcoin-cli available for OSX. I also ran into this issue, and it is because I missed one of the setup steps. Here they are for posterity!

**Install Xcode:**

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

**Install Homebrew =>**
 https://brew.sh/

**Clone the repo:**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
```

**Navigate into bitcoin directory, and run the autogen script:**

```
$ cd bitcoin
$ ./autogen.sh
```

> The autogen.sh script creates a set of automatic configuration scripts
>   that will interrogate your system to discover the correct settings and
>   ensure you have all the necessary libraries to compile the code.

**Run the configure script:**

```
$ ./configure
```

> This will automatically discover all the necessary libraries and
>   create a customized build script for your system.
>   If all went well, the configure command will end by creating the
>   customized build scripts that will allow us to compile bitcoind.

**Compile the bitcoin source:**

```
$ make
```

**Install the executables on your system:**

```
$ sudo make install
```

Default install location of bitcoind is /usr/local/bin. 
**Confirm Bitcoin Core is installed:**

```
$ which bitcoind
/usr/local/bin/bitcoind

$ which bitcoin-cli
/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-cli
```

Full disclosure this information worked for me, and it is from Andreas M. Antonopoulos' **Mastering Bitcoin** book!

Answer (score 9):

It's as simple as running `brew install bitcoin` assuming you are on macOSX and have brew installed.

Comment: Is it possible to also run a graphical user interface using this install method?

Answer (score 6):

There it's no bitcoin-cli built in the dmg file for mac os. (Unless you compile it yourself, nor is there a bitcoind from my understanding) You can execute RPC commands using the built in options under the help -> debug / then click on the console tab in the os x client.

Answer (score 3):

this should get you up and running with bitcoind on mac osx 
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md

Answer (score 1):

Best way to run Bitcoind on Mac

```
brew install bitcoin
```

One's installation done

`bitcoind` start working fine as expected

Brew download bitcoin source directory in following by default

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/bitcoin
```

simply run `bitcoind --daemon` to run the daemon with default configuration after which bitcoin data will be downloaded in :

`/Users/user_name/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin`

`tail -f debug.log`  ---> check the logs

`bitcoin-cli stop`  ---> stop the daemon