# How to install bitcoin-cli on MacOS?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, mac, installation

I have installed [bitcoin-core](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/bitcoin-core#default) with Homebrew on my MacOS, but the only package installed is Bitcoin-Qt. How do I also install bitcoin-cli?

(Just want to play with the commands for learning.)

Comment: I didn't know you could brew install Bitcoin Core until your question. If you download Bitcoin Core from bitcoincore.org bitcoin-cli is included. I'd be surprised if that wasn't the case for the brew install but this is the first time I've seen it

Comment: @MichaelFolkson Homebrew installs the same .dmg published on the official website, take a look: https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask/bitcoin-core.json

Comment: Indeed, so it includes the bitcoin-cli. Don't know why the OP doesn't have it. Maybe not following the Core docs on how to access it?

Comment: Are you following these instructions for accessing the bitcoin-cli? You should have it installed https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md#other-commands

Comment: @noitseuq Does this answer your question? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43148/bitcoin-cli-not-found-on-osx

Comment: @1440000bytes thanks, yes, it actually reveals that "there's no bitcoin-cli built in the dmg file for mac os". So you need to compile from source.

Comment: @MichaelFolkson thanks for you help! I ended up playing with Bitcoin using built-in graphical console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will install `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-cli`:

```
$ brew install bitcoin
```

This is how you install `Bitcoin Core` (MacOS app with UI):

```
$ brew install --cask bitcoin-core
```